Design guardrails to avoid noisy neighbors in a shared multitenant Postgresql DB
We own a shared PostgreSQL DB instance which is currently used by multiple services - each service has their own schema and tables residing under the respective schemas.
The obvious problem with this is one service can keep hogging the entire available IOPS because of some rogue queries. This service then becomes a noisy neighbor and impacts other service performance.
I am looking for ideas in coming up with appropriate guardrails in terms of quotas - e.g. read-quota (limit on blk_read?) and write quota (limit on bytes to be written to disk/sec ?) to prevent services abusing the DB instance.
Any ideas on how can I do this in PostgreSQL without essentially overloading DB performance while collecting these metrics? We have our DB instance hosted on AWS RDS.

Not possible. Use different instances to separate the resources

What is abusing the instance may very well be absolute necessity for the other service.

@FrankHeikens having separate instances for each of the multitude of services isn’t cost effective. Each one of them has a distinct workload. Even if I want to batch similar workloads in one dbinstance and separate out the heavier ones - any suggestions on how to best do that at run time?

@Belayer I am not denying it. But when it comes to managing the infrastructure - I need to allocate the resources so that it matches each services’ requirements. Right now we are very reactive in addressing slow queries or fixing indexing issues in one service while other services are getting impacted.

You can maybe set query_timeout to like default 10s encouraging programmers to use reasonably efficient queries. But this limit can be circumvented easily - there's no way to stop the clients to set their own longer query_timeout and it will interfere with maintenance procedures like create index.
